# C++ or Java Thread Input/Output Program - no idea where to start

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hi I am trying to write a program in C++ or Java that uses threads.  I have no idea where to start.  It is for an operating systems class.  The class only teaches concepts and no actual coding whatsoever.  The professor just hands out this assignment and said that he will provide no help at all.  Thanks a lot for helping.

Below is the program requirements:

The goal of this assignment is to create a routine which creates multiple threads, has them do work in parallel, and terminates when the last thread has finished.

The Scenario: 
There are several groups of people in a bar watching the Olympics cheering for their country. Each group will cheer for their country some given number of times, with a random pause (between 2 and 5 seconds) between each cheer. There is enough room at the bar for up to ten different groups to sit (each would be cheering for a different country).

The Program: 
The task is to write a program that will simulate these cheers using threads. The program should be called cheer.X (X being the language of choice). You may use any language that supports threading. When the program is run it should ask for the number of countries and then the name and how many times it will be cheered for. The main function will then create a thread for each team and each thread is responsible for cheering the specified number of times for the correct team at the random interval. You will submit the proper source code file for me to open and compile myself, not an executable.

An example cheer would be: “Go USA!” An example run would look something like this:
How many countries are supported at the bar? 3
Enter the first: China
How many cheers? 2
Enter the second: USA
How many cheers? 4
Enter the third: Russia
How many cheers? 3

Go USA!
Go China!
Go Russia!
Go China!
Go USA!
Go Russia!
Go USA!
Go Russia!
Go USA!
(Remember there will be a pause, and consecutive runs with the same arguments will not create the same results)

Comment: The `<thread>` header would probably be a good place to start, but since you tagged it `pthreads`, some tutorials or examples of doing something with that?

Comment: I concur with chris. If you have it at your disposal the [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in C++11 is really a simple way to get this going. Before you take this on I strongly advise reviewing how threading, mutexes, condition variables, etc., and how they work *together* is done in samples (there are lots on the web). Such knowledge is somewhat fundamental no matter what path you take (including pthreads).

Comment: I should also point this out (and believe me, it hurts to do so) If you want "simple" for modeling threading code Java threads are also a consideration. (now I need to go shower). I only bring it up because your question seems to dictate you can use any language you desire. Obviously I have a preference (and it doesn't start with J).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Also pretty easy to do in C++ (using OpenMP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++11 for multi-threading or install pthread library in your system and write a simple multi-threaded C++ code. Java is also very good option to write multi-thread program.

I would suggest before writing a code try to get the basic understanding of threads, how multiple threads are synchronized.

For pthread library help. Go through [this](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/multi-thread.html).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) is the wiki page for basic understanding of Threads.